# How run Fragment inside Activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to run GoToReminder inside my AddReminder. Can you tell me how can I do it? I tried to use that, but it doesn't work. If you have any question just feel free to ask :)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), GoToReminder.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

```
public class AddReminder extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AddReminder";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_reminder2);

        //HOW CAN I RUN FRAGMENT THERE

    }

}
```

---

```
public class GoToReminder extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_screen, container, false);
        return v;

    }
}
```

Comment: you can add fragment in XML and use it in Activity (. java class)

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: Okay ! I have posted an answer. If it helps you. you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager).

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container, GoToReminder.newInstance())
.commit()
```

R.id.container **must be declare** at add_reminder2.xml like:

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Please, read the documentation to understand how to use [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction)!

Also, you can read a [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) by Google

Comment: @teyon.abdulrehman Please, read this article https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Answer (score 0):

you can add `Frame Layout` in your activity where you want to show fragment.

**In AddReminder.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"></FrameLayout>
```

**Then in AddReminder.Java**

```
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new GoToReminder()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Yeah, but where I should add that FrameLayout if I have a ScrollView?

Comment: post a complete code or add it as per your wish .. where you want to show your fragments data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the fragment as mentioned in Android Developers doc ie

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_reminder2);
    GoToReminder gotoRemainder = new GoToReminder();

    // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
}
```

here fragment_container is the id of the layout where you want to add the fragment.this could be frame layout or some other layout where you will add your fragment.

More Details here : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui#AddAtRuntime